# Regroup array of objects based on nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, arrayofarrays

I have an Array of Object. Each Object contains another inner Array. I would like to take each inner array as outer object and put the remaining old outer elements as sub properties of newly created outer object.

**Input**

```
data = [
    {
      name: "Sam",
      ssn: 123,
      age: 25,
      hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }]
    },
    {
      name: "John",
      ssn: 234,
      age: 25,
      hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }]
    },
    {
      name: "Mathew",
      ssn: 345,
      age: 25,
      hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }, {name: "carroms"}]
    }
  ];
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
      {
        name: "cricket",
        person_details: [
          { name: "Sam", ssn: 123, age: 25 },
          { name: "John", ssn: 234, age: 25 },
          { name: "Mathew", ssn: 345, age: 25 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "football",
        person_details: [
          { name: "Sam", ssn: 123, age: 25 },
          { name: "John", ssn: 234, age: 25 },
          { name: "Mathew", ssn: 345, age: 25 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "carroms",
        person_details: [          
          { name: "Mathew", ssn: 345, age: 25 }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**What i have tried using Reduce as follows**

```
this.data = this.data.reduce(
  (a, x) => [...x.hobbies.map(h => ({ ...x, hobbies: [h] }))],
  []
);
```

Comment: Why are you putting `hobbies:` in the output? And why aren't you accessing `h.name` in the loop?

Comment: When I see code like that, I wonder if you were even trying, or you just threw something together randomly so we wouldn't close the question for not showing an attempt.

Comment: Hey man. i tried something and i dont have clear idea how we can simply achieve this by adding spread, arrow, es6 features. This can be done using multiple for loop easily but my intention here is to minimize the complexity and code.

Comment: Shortening the code using spread and reduce doesn't always mimimize complexity.  Write it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array and look for same name items for the result set.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Sam", ssn: 123, age: 25, hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }] }, { name: "John", ssn: 234, age: 25, hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }] }, { name: "Mathew", ssn: 345, age: 25, hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }, { name: "carroms" }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { hobbies, ...o }) => {
        hobbies.forEach(({ name }) => {
            var group = r.find(q => q.name === name);
            if (!group) r.push(group = { name, person_details: [] });
            group.person_details.push(o);
        })
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How will u learn these things? data.reduce((r, { hobbies, ...o }) these types of syntax are new to me.

Comment: you may have a look to [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)/[spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 2):

Simple [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) teamed up with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over the list of `hobbies`, together with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax may do the trick easily :

```js
const data = [{name:"Sam",ssn:123,age:25,hobbies:[{name:"cricket"},{name:"football"}]},{name:"John",ssn:234,age:25,hobbies:[{name:"cricket"},{name:"football"}]},{name:"Mathew",ssn:345,age:25,hobbies:[{name:"cricket"},{name:"football"},{name:"carroms"}]}],
  
      result = data.reduce((r,{hobbies, ...userData}) => (
        hobbies.forEach(({name}) => (
          match = r.find(({hobby}) => hobby == name),
          match ?
          match['person_details'].push({...userData}) :
          r.push({hobby:name, person_details: [{...userData}]})
        ))
     , r), [])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: The output should be an array, not an object

Answer (score 1):

Create an object indexed the hobby instead. When iterating over the people, create a new object with a `name` and `person_details` array if it doesn't exist yet, and then push to the `person_details` array:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Sam",
    ssn: 123,
    age: 25,
    hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }]
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    ssn: 234,
    age: 25,
    hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }]
  },
  {
    name: "Mathew",
    ssn: 345,
    age: 25,
    hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }, {name: "carroms"}]
  }
];
const peopleByHobbies = {};
for (const { hobbies, ...personData } of data) {
  for (const { name } of hobbies) {
    if (!peopleByHobbies[name]) peopleByHobbies[name] = { name, person_details: [] };
    peopleByHobbies[name].person_details.push({ ...personData });
  }
}
const output = Object.values(peopleByHobbies);
console.log(output);
```

`reduce` is arguably [not the right tool to use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnZ7jMFCa4Y) for this sort of thing, but if you want to use it:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Sam",
    ssn: 123,
    age: 25,
    hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }]
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    ssn: 234,
    age: 25,
    hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }]
  },
  {
    name: "Mathew",
    ssn: 345,
    age: 25,
    hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }, {name: "carroms"}]
  }
];
const peopleByHobbies = data.reduce((peopleByHobbies, { hobbies, ...personData }) => {
  for (const { name } of hobbies) {
    if (!peopleByHobbies[name]) peopleByHobbies[name] = { name, person_details: [] };
    peopleByHobbies[name].person_details.push({ ...personData });
  }
  return peopleByHobbies;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(peopleByHobbies);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array#reduce` .you could pass the object on each iteration using [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this `{hobbies,...b}`

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Sam", ssn: 123, age: 25, hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }] }, { name: "John", ssn: 234, age: 25, hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }] }, { name: "Mathew", ssn: 345, age: 25, hobbies: [{ name: "cricket" }, { name: "football" }, { name: "carroms" }] } ];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, {hobbies,...b}) => {
            hobbies.forEach(i => {
              acc[i.name] = acc[i.name] || {
                name: i.name,
                persional_details: []
              };
            acc[i.name].persional_details.push(b)
        })
        return acc
      }, {});

console.log(Object.values(res))
```